# XML file or database in this particular case (file updated frequently)

Tags: delphi, pascal

I have a list of URL and I should loop over them every minute or so and save the last successful access time into an XML file or database. Obviously, the URL and some short description will be saved in file as well.

I'm wondering whether XML files are reliable enough or I'm better with a database? If I must go with the database option, which one?

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also use a XML (or JSON) file storage. A simple way to build wrapper classes for a XML file is the XML Schema Binding Generator Wizard in Delphi Professional, or the Data Binding Wizard (in Enterprise / Architect). You only need to provide an example XML or a W3C [XSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) file. The wizard will create DOM based classes and binding code.

Tutorials:

- [Delphi XML Binding Wizard Tutorial](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/34110)
- [Delphi Programming Tutorial #39 - XML Data Binding](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4D78MG4CaAI)

Answer (score 2):

You can use XML file for this purpose.

There are lot of options for XML like XML Data Binding, TXMLDocument, XML with ClientDatasets etc.

The simplest option is `XML with ClientDataSet`.

This is the procedure:

- Drop a `ClientDataSet` on the the form.
- Add `FieldDefs` you need to the `ClientDataSet`.
- Right click on the ClientDataSet component and click `Create Dataset`.
- Right click again and click `Save To MyBase XML Table`.
- You XML is ready and from now onwards you can use `ClientDataSet1.LoadFromFile()` and   `ClientDataSet1.SaveToFile()` functions to load and save data.
- Then you can assign ClientDataSet DataSource to the DBGrid.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use XML. To modify an XML file you have to rewrite it, XML is not good at random read and writes, unless you can modify it only in memory and then write it when needed. Well, every minute is not a problem, unless the XML gets very large. An XML file is reliable as much as your application is in writing it. If you need more, you should consider a database. For local access something alike SQLite or Firebird embedded could be your choice.